# How to get the user's unique id of the item clicked on listview

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database

```
 DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, al);
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                name = ds.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                phonenumber=ds.getKey();
                list_user_id = getRef(position).getKey;
//                    Log.d("TAG", name);
                al.add(name);

            }
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please Check Your Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

I have a all users activity... If i click on a user i want to fetch their unique id but im unable to do that... error in line - list_user_id = getRef(position).getKey; is my way of fetching id wrong or is the method obsolete?

Comment: getKey is a function right?? `list_user_id = getRef(position).getKey;` should look like `list_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();` right? Please update your question with the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a listview you can do the following:

```
 lists.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            final String selectedFromList = (String)lists.getItemAtPosition(i);
            db= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
            db.orderByChild("username").equalTo(selectedFromList).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            String ids=datas.getKey();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });



        }
    });
```

Assuming you have a listview containing usernames and assuming you have this in your db:

```
 Users
   userid
      username://name
   userid
      username: //name
```

Using this `final String selectedFromList = (String)lists.getItemAtPosition(i);` you are able to get the item in this case the `username`. Then using the query `equalTo()` it will check the database and return to you the id of that user using `getKey()`

Comment: i tried this... its returning phone number and not unique id

Comment: the above is the only way to retrieve when you click on an item in listview, depending where you have the id, you need to retrieve. So if it is nested more than add more `child()`

Comment: shit... phone number was the main child in the db so getKey was returning number... nvm i changed it to UID now... thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the key values from Firebase DB by using Map in onDataChange method like this:

```
        Map<String, Object> td = null;
        for (com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            td = (HashMap<String, Object>) postSnapshot.getValue();
            String userName= (String) td.get("userName");
            String mobileNUM= (String) td.get("mobileNUM");
            }
```

Comment: the unique id i want to retrieve is the id firebase assigns to every user when thy sign up,,, how do i get that